# Enumerate customized to definition number

Tags: lists

In my text I have some custom stuff like

```
\begin{definition} (say this is def. 2)       
\begin{itemize}           
  \item[2.1] foo  
  \item[2.2] bar
\end{itemize}   
\end{definition}  
(some plaintext)          
\begin{definition} (say this is def. 3)       
\begin{itemize}       
  \item[3.1] foo
  \item[3.2] bar
\end{itemize}     
\end{definition}
```

and so on.

Which is a bad idea you realize at the moment your friendly reviewer suggests the blabla in ch.1. (although never used again) should also get this treatment. Ouch, here we go renaming.

Clearly, this should be fully automatizable with some clever use of enumerate. (Note all my definitions are scattered in the text, so I can't just write a block enumerate around them.) So, LaTeX shall fetch the counter variable from the definition (provided by `amsthm`) env, add a point and the counter variable from the enumerate env, and use this as item label. My documentclass is `llncs`, BTW.

If you only manage a 3a,3b,3c easily, that's also acceptable.

Comment: Please provide more information about how the `definition` environment is set up. E.g., do you employ a package such as `amsthm` or `ntheorem` to create theorem-like environments via `\newtheorem` directives? Does the document have several theorem-like environments? If so, are they numbered independently, or do they share a common counter? A separate question: Which document class do you employ?

Comment: Done, feel free to ask more :-) (But I'm not an expert...)

Comment: THX, definitely beats renumbering handish!

Comment: @Mico: add one feature, get 10 new demands :-) In your example below, you use some "label{item:defbig:1}". This is again something I want to avoid, it should be something like "label{item:defbig:putsinthe1automagically". Otherwise those refs might change with each edit either. Do you have a solution to that too?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment as a whole, and especially the concern that "those refs might change with each edit". What kind, or kinds, of edits do you have in mind. For sure, if you were to interchange the ordering of the two `\item` directives, the cross-referencing numbers would change automatically. But that's exactly as it should be, isn't it? Am I missing something? Please advise.

Comment: Oh, I see. The *labels* would be {item:defbig:1}
and {item:defbig:2}, and switching them changes nothing except it looks silly in the source. (And if I call them {item:defbig:foo} and {item:defbig:bar}, not even that.) Still have to get the concept of a label :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you employ the `llncs` document class, which provides its own definition of the `definition` environment. (Pun intended.)

I suggest you employ the `enumitem` package to create a bespoke enumerate-like environment, named `defenum` in the example below, to be used inside `definition` environments only. Observe the use of `\upshape`, to ensure that the composite numbers `3.1`, `3.2`, etc are distinguished as structural elements of the enumerated list rather than appear as part of the running text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}
% llncs provides its own 'definition' environment

% Create a bespoke enumerate-like environment:
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{defenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[defenum]{label=\upshape\thedefinition.\arabic*}

\begin{document}
\addtocounter{definition}{2} % just for this example
\begin{definition}[Some big definition] Consider:
\begin{defenum}
\item foo \label{item:defbig:1}
\item bar
\end{defenum}
\end{definition}
According to item \ref{item:defbig:1}, \dots
\end{document}
```